# Unexpected behavior when using JAXB to marshal a Map into a JSON Object

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey, jackson

I Have a Map object using the HashMap Implementation and Jersey's Jackson provider. When I try to convert the map I get the following output:

```
{"entry":{"key":"192.168.2.184","value":{"ip":"192.168.2.184","value":1.93,"lastReceivedMillis":1391419392506}},

"entry":{"key":192.168.2.186,"value":{"ip":"192.168.2.186","value":0.79,"lastReceivedMillis":1391419395874}}}
```

As you can see, the second entry has a key that is not enclosed inside quotes as the first entry's key and my json validator throws an error.

Comment: Convert Map how? Which value is not enclosed? I don't see anything missing quotes except for numbers which should not get quoted.

Comment: "key":192.168.2.186 vs "key":"192.168.2.184" One is translated to json as string the other as whatever that represents.

Comment: Ah. Yes, that is invalid. That is not something Jackson provider would do -- it won't produce invalid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I would first double-check that you are using Jackson provider. There shouldn't be a way to produce invalid JSON via data-binding, which makes me suspect that you might be using one of alternate providers (Jettison based, or so-called "natural" json).